# Notepad++ regexp search and replace to add quotes

Tags: regex, notepad++

I know there are a lot of samples out there but I just cannot seem to get this right.  Basically I have some csv data that has a field I need to surround with quotes.  (I cannot do this in excel because excel keeps changing the formatting on some text fields it is interpreting as numbers).

So the data looks like this:

```
<a whole bunch of data comma separated>,<the text I need quotes around>,_____,<bunch of following data that is comma separated>
```

as an example:

```
<....>Y2014,382.709,382.842,,28.397,28.53,0,61H25,_______,1,2<...>
```

In this case I want to find the text:

```
61H25
```

and replace it with

```
"61H25"
```

The _______ text always follows the text field need on every record.

In Notepad++ I was able to find the text with this regexp but I could not figure out what to replace it with...

```
Find: (?<=,)([^,])+(?=,_______,)
Replace:????
```

I was trying things like this for replace
"\1"\2 but the \1 seems to only have the last character of the text I needed.

Help appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: The quantifier goes inside the parenthesis, and you only have one capture group so the replacement is `"\1"`. As a side note, this is not a good way to match a field from a fixed number of fields (I guess). You should match the exact field instead of relying on what you think comes after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `+` inside the capturing group. `([^,])+` will do capture only the last character because it repeats the whole capturing group one or more times greedily. So it ends up in capturing the last character.

Regex:

```
(?<=,)([^,]+)(?=,_______,)
```

Just replace with the below:

```
"\1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I am not sure why I culd not get that to work before.  One question though why is the replacement group 1 and not 2?  Wouldn;t the (?<=,) be 1?

Comment: because there is only one group present. `(?<=...)`, `(?=...)` are lookarounds